# Count Text field Custom Options

Tags: php, magento

How do I count the number of custom options which are textfields?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Far too vague to provide any kind of meaningful answer.

Comment: i have added some custom options to a product which are text field.
now i have to count how much custom options i have which are text field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use JQuery client-side:

```
$('input:text').size();
```

More info can be found [here](http://goo.gl/u3ydY).